# MIPS Assembly - String (ASCII) Instructions

Tags: c, string, assembly, ascii, mips

I am writing an assembler in C for MIPS assembly (so it converts MIPS assembly to machine code).

Now MIPS has three different instructions: R-Type, I-Type and J-Type. However, in the `.data`. section, we might have something like `message: .asciiz "hello world"`. In this case, how would we convert an ASCII string into machine code for MIPS?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASCII text is not converted to machine code.  It is stored via the format found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

[image: ASCII Code Chart]

MIPS uses this format to store ASCII strings.  As for `.asciiz` in particular, it is the string plus the NUL character.  So, according to the sheet, A is `41` in hexadecimal, which is just `0100 0001` in binary.  But don't forget the NUL character, so: `0100 0001 0000`.

When storing the string, I'd take [Mars MIPS simulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/)'s idea and just start the memory section at a known address in memory and make any references to the label `message` set to that location in memory.

Please note that everything in the data section is neither R-type, I-type, nor J-type. It is just raw data.

Comment: And assuming the input character set is also ASCII (or maybe UTF-8), the assembler should thus simply copy the bytes from the source to the output file (at the current output position), up to the end of quoted string.  Although you do need to process C-style escape sequences like `\n` = `0xa` (LF = linefeed).

Answer (score 3):

Data is not executable and should not be converted to machine code.  It should be encoded in the proper binary representation of the data type for your target.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. My `.data` can only have `.word` or `.asciiz`. If it is `.word` then I just convert the number to its 32-bit representation. But how would you represent `.asciiz` as a machine code instruction? I need to convert it to machine code. So `array: .word 0:10` would create 10 instructions of this: `000000000000000000000000000001010`

Comment: .asciiz Is not a machine code instruction, it's an assembler directive. It tells the assembler that it should store this data in a certain format in the final binary file. In other words, the assembler is in charge of converting your representation of the data into the correct binary format, and storing it that way in the executable file.

Comment: You would not represent .asciiz as machine code instructions.  Assuming you're implementing a fairly standard ABI, you would store it as a sequence of bytes, each byte containing the ASCII value of one letter, followed by a NUL terminator.

Comment: Ah right. I'm sorry for using "machine code instruction". I meant a "sequence of bytes". Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have noted, the ascii contained in a `.ascii "string"` directive is encoded in it's raw binary format in the data segment of the object file. As to what happens from there, that depends on the binary format the assembler is encoding into. *Ordinarily* data is not encoded into machine code, *however* GNU `as` will happily assemble this:

```
.text
start:
  .ascii "Hello, world"
  addi $t1, $zero, 0x1
end:
```

If you disassemble the output in `objdump` ( I'm using the mips-img-elf toolchain here ) you'll see this:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <message>:
   0:   48656c6c    0x48656c6c
   4:   6f2c2077    0x6f2c2077
   8:   6f726c64    0x6f726c64
   c:   20090001    addi    t1,zero,1
```

The hexadecimal sequence `48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77 6f 72 6c 64` spells out "Hello, world".
I came here while looking for an answer as to why GAS behaves like this. Mars won't assemble the above program, giving an error that data directives can't be used in the text segment
Does anyone have any insight here?

Comment: Insight into what?  Why MARS has training wheels on its assembler, and doesn't let you assemble arbitrary bytes where the asm source asks for them?  Normally you'd put strings in `.section .rodata`, where they'll be linked as part of the text segment, but putting them in the text section somewhere they won't be executed is totally fine.  Or manually encoding an instruction with `.byte 0x20, 0x09, 0x00, 0x01` or something.  (Usually no reason to do so, but you can if you want.)

Comment: But if you don't understand what you're doing, it's easy to put data where execution will fall into it, and that can be confusing for beginners, hence the training wheels / nerf padding in MARS.  I think its emulator/simulator does run your program from MIPS machine code, though, so I don't think MARS is "assembling" straight into emulator internals, and restricting the .text section to only asm instructions it can parse from text.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your response. I'm not concerned with the behavior of MARS here, I was interested into why GAS allows you to use `.ascii` directives to encode raw bytes into the `.text` section. I think you've just answered that question though in saying that you can place arbitrary binary data wherever you like using these directives, potentially for manually encoding an instruction. I looked again and yes, `objdump` will attempt to interpret the binary data you inserted with these directives as instructions.

Comment: Right, `objdump` can't tell how the bytes got there.  It's all just bytes in the assembler's output file.  MARS is definitely the exception; most assemblers are like GAS and will happily assemble a line of asm source into bytes in whatever the current section is.  It's up to the programmer to make sure that's useful.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. This way of looking at things makes perfect sense, and explains why GAS allows this.